# MySQL virtual column stores age based on birthday

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement to calculate age. Now I want to set the age field as a virtual column and generate it automatically based on the birthday. How should the expression for the virtual column be written

The now() curate() function cannot be used in virtual columns

Comment: It sounds to me you would like to create a view for a calculated logical column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR, BIRTDAYCOLUMN, CURDATE()) FROM TABLE AS AGE
```

Answer (score 0):

virtual column can not use dynamic function, if you need a method to get the age value in a sql, you can use view.

eg:
mysql> show create table t_user;

| t_user |

CREATE TABLE `t_user`(
`id` bigint（20） NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar（255） DEFAULT NULL,
`birthday` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

|

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t_user;

+----+--------+---------------------+

| id | name   | birthday            |

+----+--------+---------------------+

| 1 | ming   |2011-07-1700:00:00 |

+----+--------+---------------------+

Then you can use a  view
create view t_user_with_age as select id, name, birthday, floor(datediff(curdate(), birthday)/365） from t_user;

mysql> select * from t_user_with_age;

+----+------+---------------------+------+

| id | name | birthday            | age  |

+----+------+---------------------+------+

|  1 | ming | 2011-07-17 00:00:00 |   12 |

+----+------+---------------------+------+

1 row in set (0.01 sec)